# Woocommerce Order Customer and Payment Details from Order

Tags: php, api, plugins, woocommerce, hook

I've got `$order = new WCOrder( $orderid );` in a `woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status` Filter. I can get at a bunch of stuff about the order from there, but I'd like to get from `$order` to the **Customer's phone and email address** as displayed on the Edit Order page of the Admin interface. I'd also like to get the **transaction fee** (e.g. how much Stripe or PayPal charged me for the transaction) if it's available. How do you get from $order to those values though - I lose the trail in the quickly [Woocommerce docs](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Abstract_Order.html). ? Here's my code so far:

```
  public function my_hook_function( $order_status, $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $num_items = count( $order->get_items() );

    $ret = array();
    $ret["billing_address"] = $order->get_formatted_billing_address();
    $ret["shipping_address"] = $order->get_formatted_shipping_address();
    $ret["cart_discount"] = $order->get_cart_discount();
    $ret["cart_tax"] = $order->get_cart_tax();
    $ret["order_notes"] = $order->get_customer_order_notes();

    $ret["items"] = array();
    if ( $num_items > 0 ) {
      foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        if ( 'line_item' == $item['type'] ) {
          $item_data = array();
          $item_data['name'] = $item['name'];
          $item_data['quantity'] = $item['item_meta']['_qty'][0];
          $item_data['product_id'] = $item['item_meta']['_product_id'][0];
          $item_data['subtotal'] = $item['item_meta']['_line_subtotal'][0];
          $ret["items"][] = $item_data;
        }
      }
    }

    // do stuff with $ret

    return $order_status;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code snippet appears in order details template:

```
if ( $order->billing_email ) echo '<dt>' . __( 'Email:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</dt><dd>' . $order->billing_email . '</dd>';
if ( $order->billing_phone ) echo '<dt>' . __( 'Telephone:', 'woocommerce' ) . '</dt><dd>' . $order->billing_phone . '</dd>';
```

These properties of WC_Abstract_Order class are not obvious because they are hidden behind magic methods __set and __get.